# preg_match capturing two capital letters, 3 digits and 2 capital letters, and than 7 digits

Tags: php

Okay so I have the following string

"IG 449WW 6180262 250"

I want to match the first two letters, than the second 5 letters and numbers, and than the 7 numbers and I want to capture each of these.

So I have the following preg_match:

```
  $scanned_barcode = trim(Input::get('barcode'));

    if (preg_match("/([A-Z]{2})\s(\d{3}[A-Z]{2})\s(\d{7})/", $scanned_barcode, $found)) {
        $mfg_id    = $found[1];
        $game_code = $found[2];
        $serial    = Game::find($found[3]);
}
```

Am I doing this correct? is there something I am missing? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: are the spaces always in there? if so just use explode

Comment: Nevermind what I have works, I had some other code wrong that was making it not work.
but I am curious what does explode do?

Comment: @AlexWinter [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is a function that splits a string based on a delimiter (in your case, by using the space as a delimiter, it would return an array of 4 elements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex works, but it would be easier to do this:

```
<?php

    $scanned_barcode = trim(Input::get('barcode'));

    // 'explode' the string into an array(), using the space as the delimiter
    // http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
    $found = explode(' ', $scanned_barcode);

    $mfg_id    = $found[0];
    $game_code = $found[1];
    $serial    = Game::find($found[2]);

?>
```

Comment: oh wow this is great! makes it much simpler and easier to read.